# How to use Oracle 11g client?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I may be asking something silly but I don't see any sql*plus or any GUI kind of interface to connect my Oracle server remotely. I tried SQL Plus but it's a command line interface, don't know what to do with that.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Oracle SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is a GUI client

Comment: Thanks RC, then how to use 11 g ?

Comment: Euh? click the icon "SQL Developer" over "SQL PLus" in your screenshot

Comment: RC, I didn't get any option to set-up id/password. So, I thought scott/tiger should work. But getting "Protocol adapter error".

Comment: See oracle FAQ and read the manual in order to know how to setup.

Comment: Thanks RC. I'll check the documentation.

Comment: Protocol Adapter error suggests your client or TNS_NAMEs may not be configured correctly. I always start with SQL*Plus - if you can logon and get SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL working then you know that your desktop can at least see the database.

Answer (score 0):

pl/sql developer and toad are both decent, but nonfree, Oracle gui clients.  If you're going to do a lot of work on packages or stored procs/funcs, one of these will be worth every bit of money you spend.

squirrel sql is an opensource client.  There's a squirrel-derived plugin for eclipse called SQL Explorer; it's really good for looking at your data to help get your programs right.